# Can I change the dtype of mean function in Pandas? I want to change it to int type

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Can I change the dtype of mean function in Pandas?
I will get the value in float type, but I specifically do not want to include the after decimal values,I want it only on integers, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hi there! We can Surely help, you can share some of your work or the code you have made so far, so the question becomes more clear and easy to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then apply a transformation to the result.

```py
df['mean'] = df['mean'].apply(lambda x: round(x))
```

or, if you want to truncate:

```py
df['mean'] = df['mean'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```